# Relation Baire one function and function that has the point of continuity property(PCP)

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces. A function $f: X \to Y$ is called Baire one if $f$ is a pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions $f_n: X \to Y$.

A function $f: X \to Y $  has the point of continuity property( abbreviated PCP) if for any closed set $F \subseteq X$, the restriction function $f|F$ of $f$ to $F$ has a continuity point.

It is known that if $X$ is hereditarily Baire space then $f: X \to (Y,d)$ is Baire one iff $f$ has the PCP.

Naturally we ask whether the above property still holds for any topological space $X$? or is there a Baire one function $f$ define from a topological space $X$ to a topological space $Y$ which is has no the PCP?